# Local testing of Firebase Cloud Functions failes

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

i want to test my simple cloud function on my local computer, so i dont have to deploy it everytime i change code.

I already relogged in to firebase and i'm now using the Firebase shell to call the functions

This is my cloud function code but i dont get so far to execute it

```
export const getPossibleFriend = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log(data);
    const json = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    console.log(json);
    console.log("OAHOIODHSDHHID")
    let test:string;
    const parentRef = admin.database().ref("users");

    return parentRef.once('value').then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(function(child) {
            if(child.child("nickname").val() === json["nickname"]){
                console.log(child.val());
                test = child.val();

            }
        });
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    }).then(() => {console.log(test);return test}).catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });

});
```

Everytime i use the firebase functions:shell and call:
getPossibleFriend({"data": {"nickname": "some string"},"context":{"asdf":"asdf"}})

I get:

```
firebase > i  Your code has been provided a "firebase-admin" instance.  [object Object]  Unhandled error SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
     at exports.getPossibleFriend.functions.region.https.onCall (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/lib/index.js:451:23)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:330:32)
     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
     at /Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:28:71
     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
     at __awaiter (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:24:12)
     at func (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:294:32)
     at corsHandler (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-Less-Life/firebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:350:44)
     at cors (/Users/skyy/Documents/GitHub/Waste-
Less->Lifefirebasetypescript/functions/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 500, {
  "error": {
    "status": "INTERNAL",
    "message": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```